# Maximum time to wait for url response

Tags: python, urllib

I'm making a simple update checker function for my code that I set to run every time before the bulk of the code is executed. It notifies the user that a new version is available for download.

Here's a MWE:

```
import urllib

def updater(__version__):
    try:
        # Get latest version number from master repo at Github.
        f = urllib.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisglass"
            "/django_polymorphic/master/polymorphic/__version__.py")
        s = f.read().split('"')

        if s[-2] != __version__:
            print "New version {} is available.".format(s[-2])
    except:
        pass

# Call function to check if new version is available.
__version__ = '0.1'
updater(__version__)
```

(that repo isn't mine, I'm using it in this example because I use a similar version of its `__version.py__` file)

This works fine, but I'm concerned about Github eventually taking too long to respond, which would hold back the execution of the code.

Is there a way to jump out of the `try` block after say 5 seconds have elapsed? Is this the recommended way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `urllib2`, its `urlopen` has a timeout parameter.

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data[, timeout[, cafile[, capath[, cadefault[, context]]]]])

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Comment: Isn't `urllib2`  sort of deprecated?

Comment: not if you're using python 2. In python 3, `urllib` and `urllib2` were merged to form the new `urllib` which has several subpackages.

Comment: Use the requests package if you're looking for something more versatile.

Comment: The warning at the top of the `urllib` page: "Also note that the `urllib.request.urlopen()` function in Python 3 is equivalent to `urllib2.urlopen()` and that `urllib.urlopen()` has been removed." So `urllib.urlopen()` is actually the obsolete function.